# Does Sugar remember who she had turned into a toy?

Tags: one-piece

Waiting and waiting for the next chapter to come out, I was thinking that if anything would go wrong, Doflamingo would have an easy way out of all of his problems. He could ask Sugar to turn him into a toy and nobody would even remember why they were fighting in the first place.

The world government would turn against the strawhats and everybody would go on with their every day lives. Now this plan would be perfect if Sugar would still remember about Doflamingo after he had been turned into a toy, so she could undo her magic when all threats had vanished and go into hiding or something for some time to let is all pass over.

So was any evidence shown as to whether Sugar remembers her victims or not?

Comment: great mind game :D.

Comment: No, there wasn't any evidence. Yet she could just make notes for herself. Too bad that if they would have to do this then Sugar would be knocked out again.

Comment: @ytg Why would she have to be knocked out? She would just be a normal girl if that happens. There would be no such thing as the Donquixote pirates and Riku would just become king again.

Comment: @PeterRaeves: no. There would be Donquixote pirates. They would have no idea about their captain, or why are they there or why do they fight, but they would be there and nobody would forget about them. Only about Doflamingo.

Comment: I don't think Mingo will let himself turned into a toy

Answer (score 2):

There's a way she can remember about her victims. It's mentioned in the manga [chapter 738](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_738):

> "Sugar is able to make a contract with her victims and control them,
>   leaving them with no control over their own bodies."

Read about her abilities here:  [One Piece Wikia - Sugar](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sugar)

Comment: Isn't the contract AFTER she turned them into toys and thus, she might have forgotten about the real person already before she could make the contract?

Comment: Nope, i don't think it works that way. Since we've already seen that she was able to control a whole army of toys, isn't it obvious that she knew who she was controlling.

Answer (score 2):

There is one ok piece of evidence (from the anime I'm not up to date on the manga) that says she cannot remember who she turns into a toy or even whether she did so. There is, however, even better evidence that she could communicate to her non-remembering self and turn him back.  I am not aware of any evidence that she could turn someone back at will but that is comparitively trivial as I don't believe (though they may I just don't see it) that they age while they are toys.

At the start of the arc, she had reportedly only ever let one toy free without a contract (Kyros).  She does the religously every time she uses her power (could be anytime she sees a new toy randomly appear in front of her).  When Robin is turned into a ragdoll, she makes no contract and does not try to find her to make one while Usoland is running away in terror. If she can remember, this could also be an oversight on her part, knowledge that she can't get to the toy in time anyways, or may be even an oversight by the animators (couldn't possibly be one by Oda...that is impossible).  If she could not remember Robin, this makes perfect sense and she would behave exactly like she did.

Whether she can remember or not, the statue of Kyros has stood since before he became a toy and communicates information such as his name.  The Toyfamino being contractually ordered to serve himself has free will and can walk her through whatever he needs (as long as he can get her to believe him for a second.  He cannot be the last of his "family" to be turned into a toy, however, or she would give him a different contract.

This all assumes, however, that she is loyal to him.  For a *young?* lady under constant guard by as slimey man she is constantly ordering to die, this might be a radical assumption.  Whether she is loyal or not if he does not age as a toy, has free will, and she will someday die (if he has to kill her to do it), he will likely survive the incident without being physically harmed.

Comment: In chapter 737, we can see Trebol say that he already forgot about Cavendish after he was turned into a toy. I don't remember Sugar saying so, could you provide a link or screenshot to proof? Anime proof would probably be fine too.

Comment: @PeterRaeves I didn't say she said anything like that...she doesn't say much.  I said the (weak) piece of evidence was that she didn't try to find Robin.